# A moderator is vandalizing questions and removing parts of questions he doesn't want answered. How do I report this moderator abuse?

Tags: discussion

As the question says, an abusive mod is vandalizing my questions because he is "offended" by them, removing important parts of the question to ensure they can't be answered. How can I report this mod for his behavior?

When I try to revert the question so I can get them answered, this abusive mod then locks the question so his abusive edits are preserved.

Comment: Firstly, please consider taking a look at the [tour] and learn how the site works. We edit posts here to improve them. *however*, the community does have some standards, and things should should be [on-topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The initial revision to your [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215307/blender-2-9-when-using-png-with-alpha-channel-for-texture-blender-displays-alph) is not one that would be well accepted without some refinement anyhow. There is nothing being done as an attack against you.

Comment: I removed parts from [your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215307/blender-2-9-when-using-png-with-alpha-channel-for-texture-blender-displays-alph) because they violated the [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) of this website. That is part of my duty as a moderator. The intention was that the edited version of the question could remain on the website and receive answers. The question was temporarily locked after you reverted it to its original state. This was done to give the moderation team time to look into this case.

Comment: I'm sure he was being neither abusive or vandalizing. Looking at the original post it would appear to me that he was simply trying to make it more friendly and less inflamatory - and so more likely to get attention and a meaningful and helpful answer. This site is generally a friendly, helpful, welcoming environment and the tone of your original post didn't fit well with that.

Comment: The edits were to remove negativity, not alter or vandalize the content of the question.  Although the question was written with a bit of a negative vibe, I just figured it was the result of hitting a point of frustration (We've all been there) so I attempted to "skip over" the rudeness and simply answer the question, hoping that having an answer would relieve the frustration. I also noticed Robert's edit to make the question more site-friendly, which made it A-OK in my book. There was no need to come back and re-edit the question to be insulting. This is a professional Q&A site - not a forum.

Answer (score 12):

If you have issues with moderation or questions about the site working, those should be posted here on Meta https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com , not on the main site.

Moderator Robert removed all inflammatory parts from your post which were extraneous and not strictly essential to answer your question. Edits happen all the time to make questions clearer or conform to site rules. Don't make them personal, it is not about the user, it is always about the post.

Insults, personal attacks and aggressive language besides being considered rude go against the site rules and will not be tolerated here.

Likewise rants about features or showing distaste about the software is considered off topic. This is neither the place nor the tone.

This is Q&A site run by volunteers for answering questions about Blender. We are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making or roadmaps for development of the software. If you really dislike Blender that much you are free to use any other software that better matches your needs.

Otherwise, for constructive suggestions and feature requests use https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/ or [Blender Artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org).

Before doing so consider that ideas are a dime-a-dozen. Every single one of the millions of Blender users have their own personal requests, wishes and desires, while comparatively very few people have the skills and knowledge to actually implement them.

I have restored the missing part of your question, that I'm sure Robert inadvertently removed during the cleanup process; all of which could all have been avoided in the first place if you refrained from infringing the rules.